# LEFT JOIN Difference

Tags: sql

What is the different this :

```
SELECT * FROM A a LEFT JOIN B b on a.value=b.value
```

with this :

```
SELECT * FROM A a LEFT JOIN B b on b.value=a.value
```

Comment: why not test in your database?

Comment: Functionally speaking, there is no difference between these two queries.

Comment: @Jacky . . . One test in one database does not settle whether the two constructs are equivalent (well, it would settle if they *weren't* but that's another matter).

Comment: @Jacky yeah, i have try and sometime the output result are same sometime not and when I try it by Pentaho it always different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is absolutely zero difference (except for style).

I prefer version 2):

```
on child.value = parent.value
```

because it’s more logical, readable and follows the broadly used and preferred style of:

```
if (some_variable == some_constant)
```

as `a.value` is effectively a constant when the comparison is made in table `B`.

The other way around (ie first version) feels like a [Yoda condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) to me, despite its prevalent (mis)use.

Comment: @Tim but it answers the question, which is a valid one, because SQL is whacky and it’s conceivable that it could make a difference.

Comment: My guess is that the underlying code might not be be _exactly_ the same, but performance wise it doesn't matter.  But, I agree with your Yoda comment :-)

Comment: @Bohemian yap, same like Tim. I agree with your Yoda condition comment but I don't know why sometime the result from that query are different.

Comment: @rio the addition to your question is a *different* question, so please ask it as a *new* question.